# Resumable upload manager for windows

Tags: windows, upload

As stated in title itself, I want to know if there's a resumable upload manager (like download managers) in windows ?

I have googled but couldnt find anything.

The best I could search is [upload manager](http://uploadmanager.codeplex.com/)

Comment: what protocol ? What are you uploading and to what?

Comment: Either ftp or http, anything that can fulfill the requirement. Uploading images and videos, upto 100mb max

Answer (score 2):

For FTP, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) can pause uploads when you click on the toggle processing button in the toolbar.

[image]

Your upload will be paused and resumed when you press the button once again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use the bit-torrent network. All files transferred over it are resumable.